Raw queues are deprecated and will stop working in a future version of CUPS
There is this line in error_log file: Raw queues are deprecated and will stop working in a
future version of CUPS.
When is this change scheduled?
All my printers are setup this way: lpadmin -p PRINTER_NAME -v socket://PRINTER_IP:9100 -E

What would be the new command line to use if I need to replace the configuration?

